# Insert and remove an element of a stack ADT using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, stack, adt

I want to write two functions using recursion to a stack ADT:

1. Insert an element int the ith position of the stack (using recursion).
2. Remove an element of the ith position of the stack (using recursion).

Both of them need two use only pop and/or push without using loops(while, for). In other words, the stack will "simulate" the insert and remove operations of an array.

Comment: Only the pseudocodes without recursion.

Comment: @Giovani-Should the ith position of stack be from top OR bottom? Means frm last-element counting should be done or from the first element of the stack???

Comment: Do we have the size of stack in advance,because I feel we can't get to that without size!

Comment: Yes, the size is 10.

Answer (score 0):

1. if i==0 (assuming that means the top), its trivial.  Otherwise, the only thing to do that makes any sense is to pop the top value off; once you've done that, what else do you need to do to complete your task?
2. Similar reasoning to (1).

Comment: It is good that it is incomplete. The question seems to be homework or some other type of learning exercise, and we do a bad service to the OP if we give him the full answer on a platter. Maieutics for the win!